# Memory Allocation in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: garbage-collection, profiling

Is there a good way to check line-by-line memory allocation in Julia while using a Jupyter notebook? Via the %time macro I can see that my code is spending about 20% of time in garbage collection, and I'd like to see if this can be reduced.

On a related note, are there general tips to use for reducing garbage-collection time?

Comment: How could you estimate garbage-collection?